# Get the last called method with arguments

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have this:

```
Function b
{
    Param([string] $a, [string]$b)

    (Get-PSCallStack | Select -First 1).InvocationInfo.Trim()
}

Function a
{
    b "plip" "plop"; Write-Host "a"
}

cls
a
```

If I execute the file that contains this code, I will get

```
b "plip" "plop"; Write-Host "a"
```

Where actually I would like to get:

```
b "plip" "plop";
```

So basically, I'd like to have in "b", the instruction that called "b" with its parameters as it appears in the code. I could try to achieve that with a regular expression that check if there is ";" that close the instruction, but I'm wondering if there is a better way provided by PowerShell.

Comment: `InvocationInfo` has `PositionMessage`, which clearly underlines the command for human consumption -- maybe that's enough for your purposes? You could, if you really wanted to, actually parse that to get at the command, but obviously that's extremely ugly.

Comment: @PetSerAl: so why is that not an answer?

Comment: Euh, thanks, it works.

Comment: Bizarrely enough, from Powershell 3 onwards `InvocationInfo` has a public `DisplayScriptPosition` property which also exposes `Text`... but helpfully the entire `DisplayScriptPosition` is not set.

Comment: Why not just `function b {(Get-History -Count 1).CommandLine}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ScriptPosition`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master@%7B2016-11-06%7D/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/InvocationInfo.cs#L374) internal property of `InvocationInfo` class to get script position of command:

```
Function b
{
    Param([string] $a, [string]$b)

    [System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo].InvokeMember(
        'ScriptPosition',
        'GetProperty, Instance, NonPublic',
        $null,
        (Get-PSCallStack | Select -First 1).InvocationInfo,
        $null
    ).Text
}
```